# Why does this delete the video resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a has_many through association between videos and topics, with topicable being the independent resource. I want to have a link so that **only the topicable association is deleted** and not the video nor the topic. This is what I've done so far:

In my routes.rb:

```
  resource :topicable, :only => :destroy
```

In my topicables controller:

```
def destroy
    @topicable = Topicable.find(params[:id])
    @topicable.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {redirect_to @video}
      format.js
    end
  end
```

And lastly, in my video show view:

```
<%= link_to "x", @topicable, :method => :delete, :class => 'topic_delete' %>
```

This deletes the association but also the video...which is not what I want to do. How can I fix this?

UPDATE:

this is in my video model:

```
has_many :topicables, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :topics, :through => :topicables
```

This is all that's in the topicable model:

```
belongs_to :video
belongs_to :topic
```

NOTE: This does not seem to have anything to do with :dependent => :destroy

I have this in my video model for assigning topics as a virtual attribute. This may help:

```
attr_accessor :topic_names
after_save :assign_topics

def assign_topics
  if @topic_names
    self.topics << @topic_names.map do |name|
      Topic.find_or_create_by_name(name)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: and you haven't difinded `@video` to redirect

Comment: are you sure you posted entire destroy action?

Comment: yes I did... what could this be?

Comment: so where did you get `@video` object?

Comment: I have a video resource, let's continue this in chat? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24/ruby-rails

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like your `Topicable` model has got this line

```
belongs_to :video, :dependent => :destroy
```

replace it with

```
belongs_to :video
```

Answer (score -1):

Depending on how your associations are setup between `Topicable` and `Video` make sure you don't have any `:dependent => :destroy` options set.

If you have a `has_many` set it as

```
class Whatever
  has_many :something_elses, :dependent => :nullify
end
```

That way the foreign keys will be nullified and the objects won't be destroyed

Comment: Which class would this go in? I really don't think this is what's causing this